# How do I run a chrome extension only in one window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

So there's this VPN extension which I use. But I use it only for a specific site which is always open in its independent window. If I turn it on it sets the VPN for all the windows. I want it running only on that window.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use that way. Instead, create a new Chrome profile, install the extension and then use from that profile.

Each profile has separate data folder so it can work separately. When you enable VPN on this new profile, your old profile won't be affected by this VPN connection.

If you don't know how to create a Chrome profile, [read this guide](https://pureinfotech.com/add-new-user-profiles-google-chrome/).

Comment: so if I run chrome on a profile with the vpn extention the vpn won't run on the pages of my main profile?

Comment: Yes. It works that way. You can control its cookies, saved passwords and everything separately. When you clean up cookies or cached files from this new profile, cookies & cached files on your old profile still there.